# jsPDF/AutoTable Generated PDF overlap page width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm trying to generate a PDF from a big and long HTML table with multiple columns wraping the text of all columns to fit page width. I know that I'm doing something wrong because the final PDF is overlaping page width and not breaking columns texts in new lines.

Can someone help me?

This is my code:

```js
$("#btnPDF").click(function(){
 var doc = new jsPDF('l');

  var elem = $("#basicTable")[0];
  var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(elem);
  doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {
    startY: 21,
    margin: {horizontal: 14},
    bodyStyles: {valign: 'top'},
    styles: {overflow: 'linebreak', columnWidth: 'wrap'},
    columnStyles: {}
  });

  doc.save('table.pdf');
});
```

```html
<table id="basicTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>iD</th>
      <th>Client</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>ZIPCode</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>State</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Contact1</th>
      <th>Phone1</th>
      <th>eMail1</th>
      <th>Contact2</th>
      <th>Phone2</th>
      <th>eMail2</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Antonio</td>
      <td>ANTONIO EN LA DIRECCION2</td>
      <td>DIRECCION2</td>
      <td>CP</td>
      <td>CIUDAD</td>
      <td>PROVINCIA</td>
      <td>PAIS</td>
      <td>Antonio el del nombre más largo del mundo</td>
      <td>+34666666666666</td>
      <td>antonio@elcorreomaslargo.com</td>
      <td>Antonio José el del nombre más largo del mundo</td>
      <td>+34666666666666</td>
      <td>antonio@elcorreomaslargo.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="btnPDF">
  Generate PDF
</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/2.3.2/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/we4dfhoo/)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: any answer for this I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for your problem. It isn't pretty, but I've been using it.

You can create several new tables that have the content of the one long table. It would be like this:

```
<table id="basicTablePart1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>iD</th>
      <th>Client</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Antonio</td>
      <td>ANTONIO EN LA DIRECCION2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="basicTablePart2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>ZIPCode</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>DIRECCION2</td>
      <td>CP</td>
      <td>CIUDAD</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Let me know if anyone's found a smarter solution!